# I want to display data in the controller using the codeigniter model

Tags: database, model, controller, codeigniter-3

I want to display data on the controller

```
public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        if(!isset($_SESSION)){
            session_start();
        }
        if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {
            redirect('auth/login');
        }
        $managemenu =  new Managemenu();
        $get_data = $managemenu->index($_SESSION['admin_level'],$GLOBALS['PAGE_DISTRIK']);
        if(empty($get_data['validPage'])){
            redirect('auth/login');
        }
        $this->getdata = $get_data;
        $this->load->model('Model_distrik');
    }

public function index()
    {
        $data['page'] = 'v_distrik';
        $data['title'] = 'List Distrik';
        $data['menu'] = $this->getdata['menu'];
        $data['distrik'] = $this->Model_distrik->getDataDistrik();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r ($data['distrik']);
        echo "</pre>";
        die();

        $this->load->view('main',$data);
    }
```

I've tried a number of times but the results are like
 this error message: undefined property: district :: $ model_district

class Model_distrik extends CI_Model {

```
public function getDataDistrik(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('distrik');
    $this->db->where("Deleted", 0);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $query;
}
```

}

Comment: The code is working fine, there must be other codes that causing that error. What class does the controller extending to?

Comment: problem is solved,thanks